# OMNET makefile.in configuration

Tags: c++, makefile, omnet++

I´m using OMNET 4.3.1 to intgerate with a class that I want to use threads. When OMNET compiles it says that "this file requires compiler and library support for the ISO c++ 2011 statndard. This support is currently experimental and must be enabled with -std=c++11 or -gnu=c++11 compiler options.

So I looked for a way to enable this parameter in OMNET but I could not find the place to set it . I was wondering if I could configure in Makefile.inc but I don´t know how to make it.

Can anyone help me with some information ? I´m using ubuntu 13.04 with gcc 4.7.3.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Library support for the ISO c++ 2011 standard in omnet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41013033/library-support-for-the-iso-c-2011-standard-in-omnet)

Answer (score 1):

in makefile.in u will find the CXXFLAGS 
set it to: CXXFLAGS = --std=c++0x and save.

note that each time u run ./configure this will be set back to default

in windows version MinGW has a known string issue which does not support c++11, and u have to fixed it, but it works well in linux systems