# Library support for the ISO c++ 2011 standard in omnet

Tags: c++, c++11, omnet++, veins

I am using OMNET 4.4. When OMNET compiles it says that

> this file requires compiler and library support for the ISO c++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental and must be enabled with -std=c++11 or -gnu=c++11 compiler options.

Also following error appears:

```
/veins/modules/application/traci/TraCITestApp.h:78:36: warning: non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
```

I am using windows 10 and I could not find solution to it in internet .

Can anyone help me with some information ?

Comment: The message says your compiler only has experimental support. So which compiler are you using? It's probably a bit old. Second, the error you post is not an error but a warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this warning is not coming up from the build of OMNeT++, but from the build of Veins. It is not the same. OMNeT++ 4.4 builds without C++11 support fine, but it seems that recent versions of Veins may need it. However again, this is a warning. OMNeT++ 4.6 and later can be configured with the `-std=c++11`.

You may need to update your compiler, too as any recent compiler fully supports c++11 since at least 3 years.

Comment: @ Rudi: Thank you very much for your prompt answer. I installed omnet 4.6 and now its working.

Comment: @zekarerhs If this answered your question, don't forget to mark it as solved so other people will find it more easily.